# Detecting which list element was clicked using jquery (list is added dynamically)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Case1: List is present in the html already

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

The clicked li element is detected using

```
$('#list1 li').bind('click', function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Above works fine.

Case 2:

Now if the list is added dyamically

```
<div id="testDiv">
</div>

var output = '<ul id="list1">' +
             '<li>One</li>' + 
             '<li>Two</li>' +
             '</ul>';

$('#testDiv').html(output);
```

I try to detect the clicked li element using same code

```
$('#list1 li').bind('click', function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

In this case, it does not detect

Comment: did you add jQuery in your page? Did you put the script in a dom ready handler? is there any error in your browser console?

Comment: Option 1 is the correct way.

Comment: option 1 should work fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T6CVD/1/

Comment: Are you creating these elements dynamically? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Hm, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y7fD/).

Comment: Are you remembering to put option 1 inside a document ready?

Comment: @Barmar Actually I'd use event delegation: `$('#list1').on('click', 'li', ...)`

Comment: Yes, I am creating everything dynamically

Comment: @user544079 that makes event delegation an even more attractive proposition, especially if the `#list1` element is always present and it's only the contents of it that change dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar oh, and please don't link to that question - it's very old and the top rated answers are all very out of date, recommending obsolete methods of performing event delegation.

Comment: @Alnitak Got a better one for me to link to? I'll replace my bookmark.

Answer (score 4):

*Assuming* that you've got jQuery correctly loaded, and that you put your jQuery related code in a ["document ready"](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler, I'd recommend "event delegation", such that you just register a single event handler on a static ancestor element.

Clicks received in the `li` descendants will "bubble up" to the ancestor element, but jQuery will ensure that `this` is set to the element that was actually clicked:

```
$('#testDiv').on('click', 'li', function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

So long as the static ancestor remains present on the page you can dynamically change its contents as much as you please and the event handler will continue to work.